# TTL or RTL, which is better?

Tags: transistors, logic-gates, ttl

Is there an advantage to using one or the other?
[image: TTL-NAND]

[image: RTL-NAND]

Comment: You're designing an IC or building from discretes? If you're building from discretes, do you have a source for dual-emitter BJTs?

Comment: Using discrete components. I simply use two individual bjt's and  connect their base and collector together to create a equivalent transistor.

Comment: One is TTL, the other is not (RTL).

Comment: Better *according to what criterium*?

Answer (score -3):

The NASA Lunar Lander used Fairchild uL dual NORs, each with 3 inputs. For everything. Flipflops were implemented out of these dual NORs.

TTL was not yet available when the Lander's computers were designed. TTL came along for the inertial-guidance systems of the Polaris/Posiden missiles.

Comment: How does this answer the question that was asked?

Comment: Are you talking about NOR logic gates, or is NOR a abbreviation?

Comment: Are you trying to say, "If you're designing something in 1967, use RTL, if you're designing something in the mid-1970's, use TTL"?